# PostgreSQL COPY To STDOUT takes lot of time for large amount of data

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have 4 tables with almost 770K rows in each table and I am using `COPY TO STDOUT` command for data backup. I am using `pg` module for database connection. Following code shows database client connection:

```
  var client = new pg.Client({user: 'dbuser', database: 'dbname'});
  client.connect();
```

Following is the *code* for backup:

```
  var stream1 = client.copyTo("COPY table_name TO STDOUT WITH CSV");
  stream1.on('data', function (chunk) {
    rows = Buffer.concat([rows, chunk]);
  });

  stream1.on('end', function () {
    myStream._write(rows, 'hex', function(){
      rows = new Buffer(0);
      return cb(null, 1);
    });
  });

  stream1.on('error', function (error) {
    debug('Error: ' + error);
    return cb(error, null);
  });
```

`myStream` is the object of class which inherits `stream.Writable`. `myStream._write()` will concatenate streams in a buffer and at the end, the data in buffer is stored in a file.

It works fine for small amount of data but it takes *lot of time* for large data.

I am using *PostgreSQL 9.3.4* and *NodeJS v0.10.33*

The `create table` statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  date_time timestamp without time zone,
  dev_id integer,
  type integer,
  value1 double precision,
  value2 double precision,
  value3 double precision,
  value4 double precision,
  message character varying(255),
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
)
```

Here is the execution plan:

```
dbname=# explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select * from table_name;
                                                         QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.table_name  (cost=0.00..18022.19 rows=769819 width=105) (actual time=0.047..324.202 rows=769819 loops=1)
 Output: id, date_time, dev_id, type, value1, value2, value3, value4, message, created_at, updated_at
 Buffers: shared hit=10324
 Total runtime: 364.909 ms
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the same with `psql` to see if the issue is the server returning the data, or your script processing it? Also, how long is “a lot of time”, and how big is your table? Do you have any large columns in there?

Comment: It takes more that 30 mins to take backup of single table both using `psql` and from code. Table contains 11 columns

Comment: What's the size of the table (in pages or bytes)? Things are very different if your columns contain a single integer or a multi-megabyte `text` field for instance. Also, what's the I/O load on your server?

Comment: That's probably overhead on the Node.js side. I can export 1 million rows to a file (using `copy ... to stdout`) with about 500MB using `psql` in about 10 seconds.

Comment: But, if I am running command on command prompt using `psql`, then also it takes about 1.30 hrs to execute

Comment: That could indicate a network problem or the size of your table is simply _that_ big. How big is the generated file if you do it from `psql`? Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for that table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: That table doesn't look overly wide. So how big _is_ the local file if you export the data through `psql`? Also: please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select * from table_name;`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `rows = Buffer.concat([rows, chunk]);` to me, this looks like you are collecting everything you recieve into an ever-expanding buffer and write this buffer to a file, once you have received an EOF.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring how such a table could take that long to dump. What’s the setup? Is the database on a disk local to the PostgreSQL server? How busy is that disk? Are other queries running normally? Can you include the output of `top` (the header lines should be enough) on the machine running PostgreSQL and of `select * from pg_stat_activity;` while the query runs?

Comment: File size is: 69.724mb. It takes almost 15 seconds to copy data to a file but for stdout it it taking about 1.30 hrs.

Comment: @joop yes, I am writing all data to a buffer and at the end, write buffer to file. I think this is causing the issue.